# blazor server app 404 on publish at / on IIS

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor app that is running fine on localhost.

Here's the steps I have taken to put my project live.

1. Setup new Windows Server on AWS.
2. Enabled IIS.
3. Installed ASP.NET Core Runtime Hosting Bundle.
4. Installed the URL Rewrite module.
5. Setup a SSL cert and DNS settings to point to IP.
6. Configured bindings to port 443 and picked the cert added path wwwroot/projectname
7. published my project using web deploy.

However, when navigating to my url I'm seeing 404 resource not found.

Only thing that is different is that the server added a web config to get it to run in IIS which looks like this.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 8b081fc5-0f9d-4426-b9cf-90f4d30b5527-->
```

Anyone point me in the right direction as to what I should be looking out for or steps I may have missed as this is the first time I've attempted publishing a Blazor-Server application.

Comment: Is your website pointing to the root directory of your published application?

Comment: Where do you want to publish this app, under the default site or create a new site? And you need to put the project folder in the root of the published site. Something like this:  `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\<sitename>\<your project>`. In addition, can you provide the error page shootcute and the corresponding sub-status code which will help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my IIS, I have "AspNetCoreModuleV2" not "AspNetCoreModule" like this:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 8b081fc5-0f9d-4426-b9cf-90f4d30b5527-->
```

See: [Hosting A Blazor Visual Studio Project Directly In IIS](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/56)